# How to fit a quadratic model with a < 0 in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, quadratic

I'm fitting a quadratic model to the diversity of bees along an elevational gradient. I'm supposing there will be a maximum somewhere along the gradient, thus my model should have a negative "a" coefficient. This is working for 3 genera, but with the fourth one (*Exaerete*) the "a" becomes positive. The graph below shows all 4 fits, and we can see that the blue line is the only one "incorrect":

[image: Euglossina richness]

Isolating this genus, we can see clearly why it's "incorrect":

[image: Exaerete richness]

There's a quadratic and a linear model together. The quadratic one makes sense given the data points, but not so much sense biologically. I want to force the command to generate a negative "a" (thus giving an "optimum" altitude probably much lower than the given in the first graph, i.e. 1193 m), how can I do that? The command in R used to generate the model was

```
fitEx2 <- lm(num~I(alt^2)+alt,data=Ex)
```

And the data is

```
Ex <- data.frame(alt=c(50,52,100,125,130,200,450,500,525,800,890,1140),
                 num=c(3,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: This is more of a "what tweaks to my methods should I use" or "suggest alternate methods" sort of question. These are off-topic on SO. Voting to migrate to CrossValidated.com

Comment: @42-, I wouldn't agree. The ultimate question is very clear: "*I want to force the command to generate a negative "a"*" (except for mentioning that `a` is the coefficient of the quadratic term).

Comment: @Julius Yes, in Brazil the default form of the equation is y = ax2 + bx + c.

Comment: @42- Julius is right. Sorry if I wasn't more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Optimization Task View](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Optimization) lists several packages that solve least-squares problems, allowing (linear) constraints on the coefficients, for example *minpack.lm*.

```
library(minpack.lm)
x <- Ex$alt; y <- Ex$num
nlsLM(y ~ a*x^2 + b*x + c, 
      lower=c(-1, 0, 0), upper=c(0, Inf, Inf), 
      start=list(a=-0.01, b=0.1, c=0))
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: y ~ a * x^2 + b * x + c
##    data: parent.frame()
##     a     b     c 
## 0.000 0.000 1.522 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 5.051
## 
## Number of iterations to convergence: 27 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

By the way, this function is also more reliable than `nls` and tries to avoid the "zero gradient".
Would be helpful if users will more often take advantage of the many CRAN Task Views.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to CRAN Task Views. I played with different upper values for a, and this led me to different curves with different vertices, i.e. no natural solution at sight.

Answer (score 2):

We are dealing with a restricted estimation, which can be conveniently handled with, e.g., `nls`. For instance,

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) - 0.01 * x^2 + 0.1 * x

nls(y ~ -exp(a) * x^2 + b * x + c, start = list(a = log(0.01), b = 0.1, c = 0))
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: y ~ -exp(a) * x^2 + b * x + c
#    data: parent.frame()
#        a        b        c 
# -4.66893 -0.03615 -0.01949 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 97.09
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.25e-08
```

where using `exp` helps to impose the negativity constraint. Then your desired quadratic term coefficient is

```
-exp(-4.66893)
[1] -0.009382303
```

However, it is likely that, since `lm` estimates a positive coefficient, in your particular case `nls` will crash by approaching −∞ as to make the coefficient zero.

A more stable approach may be using, e.g., `optim`:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100) - 0.01 * x^2 + 0.1 * x
lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x       I(x^2)  
#    -0.04359      0.04929      0.04343  

fun <- function(b) sum((y - b[1] * x^2 - b[2] * x - b[3])^2)
optim(c(-0.01, 0.1, 0), fun, method = "L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), upper = c(0, Inf, Inf))
# $par
# [1] 0.00000000 0.05222262 0.01441276
# 
# $value
# [1] 95.61239
# 
# $counts
# function gradient 
# 7        7 
# 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# 
# $message
# [1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

which suggests a linear model. In fact, since your model is very simple, most likely that is indeed the theoretical optimum and you may want to rethink your approach. For instance, maybe you can consider some observations as outliers and alter the estimation accordingly?

Comment: nls gives two different errors: if I include data=Ex, it says "singular gradient"; if I don't, it says "parameters without starting value in 'data': num, alt". Looking for the other approach now.

Comment: @Rodrigo, try to provide some reasonable starting values as I did in my example.

Comment: optim really gave "a" = 0. This makes me think... But I still would like to try the first approach, haven't found out yet the reason for the error.

Comment: @Rodrigo, if you could add your data to the question (with `dput`), I may be able to suggest something more.

Comment: Added my data to the end of the question. Tweaking the initial values in nls ain't working...

Comment: @Rodrigo, I tried something else and it didn't help. Looking at the data plot it doesn't seem like it's possible to achieve what you want without additional adjustments.

Comment: Well, looks like I'll have to accept the maximum diversity at sea level, what is not what I expected, but it's not illogical either. Thank you very much for your help!